# Embedded Jetty allowing HTTP TRACE / TRACK Methods

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I was trying to figure out the jetty doc on the HTTP Trace and Track but could not find much. Is this statement true - "HTTP trace is disabled by default, but for embedded it is still enabled. " ? If it is, can someone please share the embed jetty doc link on how to disable it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no "Track" method.

When using a WebApp, aka a WAR file (or exploded WAR file), the default descriptor will disable the HTTP `TRACE` method.

This is true for Standalone Jetty, and Embedded Jetty.

If you want to enable the `TRACE` method, you have to supply a custom default descriptor to the WebApp that wants to honor the `TRACE` method.  (Using the [`WebAppContext.setDefaultDescriptor(String)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-webapp/11.0.8/org.eclipse.jetty.webapp/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setDefaultsDescriptor(java.lang.String)) method in embedded, or in XML)

If you are using something that isn't a WebApp (eg: a Handler, a ScopedHandler, a ServletContextHandler, etc) then you have no restrictions on `TRACE` method usage.

Once you have `TRACE` enabled, it's up to your chosen web library to answer that method, as Jetty itself will not participate with production of the `TRACE` response.